# Unitary similarity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have a matrix:
$ A= \dfrac{i}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&1\\-2&1&1\\1&1&-2\end{bmatrix} $
Could someone explain me how to find a corresponding diagonal matrix for a diagonalizable matrix or linear map by unitary similarity transformation, please?(in the simplest way, if it's possible)

Comment: Can you find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix and thus its eigenvalues?

Comment: I can, but something is wrong with my calculations. I have: $ \lambda(i-\frac{\lambda}{3})(i+\frac{\lambda}{3})$

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? For sure $\;A\;$ is singular (since its determinant is zero, say), so one of its eigenvalues **must** be zero...and your char. polynomial has zero as one of its eigenvalues, so what makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: @DonAntonio: That is correct, but I know that wolphramalpha always knows better http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=i%2F3%7B%7B1%2C-2%2C1%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C-2%7D%7D

Comment: @Amzoti: Could you tell me where is my mistake:

Comment: Oh, dear: don't you believe everything WA says is true, though in this case (and other simple ones) it may be true. you just check your characterisitic polynomial...

Comment: Okey I will calculate it again. But what I should do with the diagonalization - this is the bottom line?

Answer (score 1):

$$|xI-A|=\left(\frac i3\right)^3\begin{vmatrix}x-1&2&-1\\2&x-1&-1\\-1&-1&x+2\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=-\frac i{27}(x-1)^2(x+2)+4-2(x-1)-4(x+2)=$$

$$=-\frac i{27}\left(x^3-3x+\color{red}2-2x+\color{red}2+\color{red}4-4x-\color{red}8\right)=-\frac i{27}(x^3-9x)=$$

$$=-\frac i{27}x(x-3)(x+3)$$

and the above is close (at least) to what you got (and not what Amzoti got), so you better check stuff.

Comment: But why are you boosting to the third power $\frac{i}{3}$ in the beginning?

Comment: Because I think it's much easier, @jaranna . I'm using the well known property for $\;n\times n\;$ matrices $$|cA|=c^n|A|$$

Comment: But the matrix is $c|A|$ in the problem?

Comment: According to what you wrote, the matrix is $\;cA'\;$ , with $\;A'\;$ as in my answer and $\;c=\frac i3\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

@Amzoti: Could you tell me where is my mistake: $A= \frac{i}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1&-2&1\\-2&1&1\\1&1&-2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{i}{3}&\frac{-2i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}\\\frac{-2i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}\\\frac{i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}&\frac{-2i}{3}\end{bmatrix} \\ A_{\lambda} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{i}{3}-\lambda&\frac{-2i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}\\ \frac{-2i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}-\lambda&\frac{i}{3}\\ \frac{i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}&\frac{-2i}{3}-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$

After transformations($C_{1}-C_{2}$ and $W_{2}+W_{1}$), I have:
$A_{\lambda} = \begin{bmatrix} i-\frac{\lambda}{3}&\frac{-2i}{3}&\frac{i}{3}\\ 0&\frac{-i-\lambda}{3}&\frac{2i}{3}\\ 0&\frac{i}{3}&\frac{-2i-\lambda}{3}\end{bmatrix}$

So then I wanted to develop it with the first column:
$(i-\frac{\lambda}{3})(-1)^{2} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1-\lambda}{3}&\frac{2i}{3}\\\frac{i}{3}&\frac{-2i-\lambda}{3} \end{bmatrix}$

And the CP: $\lambda(i-\frac{\lambda}{3})(i+\frac{\lambda}{3})=0$